# Angular 6 Directive Error - Can't bind to 'appClickEvent' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Created a module with a directive inside that will catch a click event from a button.

**click.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickEvent]'
})
export class ClickDirective {
  private el:any;
  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef,
  ) {}

  @Input() appClickEvent: any;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) clickEvent(event:any) {
    console.log(this.appClickEvent) // {label: 'Foo'}
  }
}
```

**Usage in a component**

I want to get the data `{label: 'Foo'}` and pass it to the `@HostListener` in the `click.directive.ts`.

```
<button [appClickEvent]="{label: 'Foo'}">Click Foo</button>
```

**my.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ClickDirective } from './click.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ClickDirective
  ],
  declarations: [
    ClickDirective
  ]
})
@NgModule()
export class McAnalyticsModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
// ... other modules
import { MyModule } from '@app/my/my.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // .. .other modules
    MyModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Error**

> Can't bind to 'appClickEvent' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("][appClickEvent]="{label: 'Foo'}">Foo")

Answer (score 0):

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzfwzh)

click.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickEvent]'
})
export class ClickDirective {
  private el:any;
  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef,
  ) {}

  @Input() appClickEvent: any;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) clickEvent(event:any) {
    console.log("your output");
    console.log(this.appClickEvent)
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { ClickDirective } from './click.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,ClickDirective ], exports: [ClickDirective],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

html:

```
<button appClickEvent="{label: 'Foo'}">Click Foo</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inject `McAnalyticsModule` in `app.module.ts` Not `MyModule`. So angular didn't find the `McAnalyticsModule`.

Include `McAnalyticsModule` in `app.module.ts` like this:

```
import { McAnalyticsModule } from '@app/my/my.module';     //<== Remove MyModule class 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // .. .other modules
    McAnalyticsModule,          //<== Remove MyModule class 
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is working example:  [Angular 6 Directive](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1znojv)